# PHPCrawl - Attempted to call method "getURIContent" on class "PHPCrawlerUtils"

Tags: symfony, phpcrawl

I'm trying to use PHPCrawl with Symfony2. I've first installed the PHPCrawl library using composer, then I created a folder "DependencyInjection" in my bundle, where I put the class "MyCrawler" which extends PHPCrawler. I configured it as a service.
Now, when I launch the crawling process, Symfony gives me the aforementioned error :

Attempted to call method "getURIContent" on class "PHPCrawlerUtils"

and I can't figure out why since the class exists, and the method exists.

Here is my controller action :

```
    /**
 * Parcours le site concerné
 * 
 * @Route("/crawl", name="blog_crawl")
 * @Template()
 */
public function crawlAction($url = 'http://urlexample.net')
{               
    // Au lieu de créer une instance de la classe MyCrawler, je l'appelle en tant que service (config.yml)
    $crawl = $this->get('my_crawler');

    $crawl->setURL($url);

    // Analyse la balise content-type du document, autorise les pages de type text/html
    $crawl->addContentTypeReceiveRule("#text/html#"); 

    // Filtre les url trouvées dans la page en question - ici on garde les pages html uniquement
    $crawl->addURLFilterRule("#(jpg|gif|png|pdf|jpeg|svg|css|js)$# i"); 

    $crawl->enableCookieHandling(TRUE);

    // Sets a limit to the number of bytes the crawler should receive alltogether during crawling-process.
    $crawl->setTrafficLimit(0);

    // Sets a limit to the total number of requests the crawler should execute.
    $crawl->setRequestLimit(20);

    // Sets the content-size-limit for content the crawler should receive from documents.
    $crawl->setContentSizeLimit(0);

    // Sets the timeout in seconds for waiting for data on an established server-connection.
    $crawl->setStreamTimeout(20);

    // Sets the timeout in seconds for connection tries to hosting webservers.
    $crawl->setConnectionTimeout(20);

    $crawl->obeyRobotsTxt(TRUE);
    $crawl->setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0");

    $crawl->go();

    // At the end, after the process is finished, we print a short 
    // report (see method getProcessReport() for more information) 
    $report = $crawl->getProcessReport(); 

    echo "Summary:".'<br/>'; 
    echo "Links followed: ".$report->links_followed.'<br/>'; 
    echo "Documents received: ".$report->files_received.'<br/>'; 
    echo "Bytes received: ".$report->bytes_received." bytes".'<br/>'; 
    echo "Process runtime: ".$report->process_runtime." sec".'<br/>';
    echo "Abort reason: ".$report->abort_reason.'<br/>';


    return array(
        'varstuff' => 'something'
    );
}
```

Here is my service class MyCrawler in the DependencyInjection folder:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\DependencyInjection;

use PHPCrawler;
use PHPCrawlerDocumentInfo;

/**
 * Description of MyCrawler
 *
 * @author Norman
 */
class MyCrawler extends PHPCrawler{

    /**
     * Récupère les infos d'une url
     * 
     * @param PHPCrawlerDocumentInfo $pageInfo
     */
    public function handleDocumentInfo(PHPCrawlerDocumentInfo $pageInfo)
    {                
        $page_url = $pageInfo->url;        
        $source = $pageInfo->source;
        $status = $pageInfo->http_status_code;

        // Si page "OK" (pas de code erreur) et non vide, affiche l'url
        if($status == 200 && $source!=''){
            echo $page_url.'<br/>';

            flush();            
        }
    }    
}
```

I've also searched for help on the sourceforge PHPCrawl forum but without success so far...
I should add that I'm using PHPCrawl 0.83 from here :

https://github.com/mmerian/phpcrawl/

and here is the class where the problem seems to appear :

```
<?php
/**
 * Class for parsing robots.txt-files.
 *
 * @package phpcrawl
 * @internal
 */  
class PHPCrawlerRobotsTxtParser
{ 
  public function __construct()
  {
    // Init PageRequest-class
    if (!class_exists("PHPCrawlerHTTPRequest"))    include_once($classpath."/PHPCrawlerHTTPRequest.class.php");
    $this->PageRequest = new PHPCrawlerHTTPRequest();

  }

  /**
   * Parses a robots.txt-file and returns regular-expression-rules corresponding to the containing "disallow"-rules
   * that are adressed to the given user-agent.
   *
   * @param PHPCrawlerURLDescriptor $BaseUrl           The root-URL all rules from the robots-txt-file should relate to
   * @param string                  $user_agent_string The useragent all rules from the robots-txt-file should relate to
   * @param string                  $robots_txt_uri    Optional. The location of the robots.txt-file as URI.
   *                                                   If not set, the default robots.txt-file for the given BaseUrl gets parsed.
   *
   * @return array Numeric array containing regular-expressions for each "disallow"-rule defined in the robots.txt-file
   *               that's adressed to the given user-agent.
   */
  public function parseRobotsTxt(PHPCrawlerURLDescriptor $BaseUrl,   $user_agent_string, $robots_txt_uri = null)
  {
    PHPCrawlerBenchmark::start("processing_robotstxt");

    // If robots_txt_uri not given, use the default one for the given BaseUrl
    if ($robots_txt_uri === null)
      $robots_txt_uri = self::getRobotsTxtURL($BaseUrl->url_rebuild);

    // Get robots.txt-content
    $robots_txt_content = PHPCrawlerUtils::getURIContent($robots_txt_uri, $user_agent_string);

    $non_follow_reg_exps = array();

    // If content was found
    if ($robots_txt_content != null)
    {
      // Get all lines in the robots.txt-content that are adressed to our user-agent.
      $applying_lines = $this->getUserAgentLines($robots_txt_content, $user_agent_string);

      // Get valid reg-expressions for the given disallow-pathes.
      $non_follow_reg_exps = $this->buildRegExpressions($applying_lines, PHPCrawlerUtils::getRootUrl($BaseUrl->url_rebuild));
    }

    PHPCrawlerBenchmark::stop("processing_robots.txt");

    return $non_follow_reg_exps;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I solved my own question. What happens here is that the mmerian PHPCrawler package autoloads every class in the libs directory when installed in Symfony2. Now, there are 2 classes named PHPCrawlerUtils. The first is in its own folder, the second is missing the getURIcontent method. And after autoload is over, the second one prevails.
In the main class PHPCrawler, the constructor loads every correct classes he needs "if the class doesn't already exist". That's why the correct class isn't loaded.
Finally, I included the PHPCrawlerUtils class without condition about its existence.